# Apply modifier on if else block

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

As seen in the code below, I have applied `frame()` modifier in the  `if` block and `else` block.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if model.mode == .active {
            activeList
                .frame(minWidth: 200)
        } else {
            trashedList
                .frame(minWidth: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I remove duplication of `frame(minWidth:)`?

More generally, is there a way where outcome of if else can have modifiers at a common place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advice you to use `Group` as it doesn't change your layout such as :

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Group {
            if model.mode == .active {
                activeList
            } else {
                trashedList
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 200)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though all of the above answers are correct, my personal opinion is to do something like below. And i prefer the @paul's view having a group can reduce your view modifier's replication.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        let listView = model.mode == .active ? activeList : trashedList
        
        listView
            .frame(minWidth: 200)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can define your own modifier

```
struct MyDefaultWidthModifier: ViewModifier {    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .frame(minWidth: 200) // you can store this as a variable based on your needs
    }
}
```

Elegant Usage:

```
NavigationView {
        if model.mode == .active {
            activeList
                .modifier(MyDefaultWidthModifier())
        } else {
            trashedList
                .modifier(MyDefaultWidthModifier())
        }
    }
```

Solution 2: If you don't want to write the modifier every time, extend the [ListStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle). Example below:

```
struct MyListStyle: ListStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        // This just extends the default List appearance, but you can return

        List(configuration)
            .modifier(MyDefaultWidthModifier()) // Along with whatever other styles you 
    }
}

extension ListStyle where Self == MyListStyle {
    static var myListStyle: MyListStyle { .init() }
}
```

Then in your top-level ContentView, add the modifier:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if model.mode == .active {
            activeList
        } else {
            trashedList
        }
    }.listStyle(.myListStyle)
}
```

Comment: How can this code be modified such that .modifier would get called only once? I will have to add .modifier every time I add more `if else` in this code snippet

Comment: Please check the updated answer, play with the list style to achieve the expected behavior